# Floated divs are overlapping?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Currently, one div is floated - my question is why are two divs overlapping even if the dimensions are set in every one of them? How can I fix this?

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block1">
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
    </div>
 </div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.wrapper {border:black solid;width:500px;height:1000px}
.block1 {width:300px;height:300px;float:right;border:solid red;}
.block2 {width:300px;height:300px;border:solid green;}
```

**jsfiddle here -** http://jsfiddle.net/FLwUA/1/

Comment: Because `300 + 300 > 500`.

Comment: Do you mean, that one `div` should be above the second one or that they shouldn't overlap **and** stay in the same line?

Comment: yes, I mean how to prevent them from overlapping - in this case I do not want them to be side by side. If wrapper is 500px and both have fixed width, both can not fit inside and so the second div should stay under.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are giving them defined widths using pixels - your wrapper width is only `500px`, however you are using `300px` by `300px` divs inside which is equal to `600px` so it'll end up outside the container div. You could use percentages in relation to the parent div like so. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLwUA/2/).

```
.wrapper {border:black solid; width:500px;height:1000px}
.block1 {width:49%;height:300px;float:right;border:solid red;}
.block2 {width:49%;height:300px;border:solid green;}
```

Alternately, if you want to keep the fixed width and have one over the other if they are too large, you could just use `float` on the second block. Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLwUA/5/).

```
.wrapper {border:black solid; width:500px;height:1000px}
.block1 {width:300px;height:300px;float:right;border:solid red;}
.block2 {width:300px;height:300px;float:left; border:solid green;}
```

Comment: Thank you. Floating div weas the problem

Comment: This is one of the few times I haven't gotten completely fed up doing this with CSS 'the right way' and just used a table. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The two divs overlap because one is fixed in the DOM layout (the non floated one) and the other is effectively removed from the DOM structure (the floated one) and is free to overlay as the two will not fit side by side in the parent container due to the width being two small.

To fix this there are several options, depending what you mean by fix.

You can use the CSS 'clear' attribute on the non floated div to force it to have nothing on one or both sides of it ('clear:both;' or 'clear:left;' in the scenario given).

or

You can set the non-floated div to be floated, which will also take it out of the DOM layout so that it is now in the same situation as the other floated div.

---

**Additional**

Just for information in case all the floating objects become an issue. One way to achieve the same result without floating the divs is to use the "display:inline-block;" CSS attribute on both of them, but you would need to swap the ordering of the two divs around in the HTML to get the same layout.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. floating second div to the right fixed it.

Comment: No problem, just be wary of floating all of your divs as this might cause strange results based on what the rest of your DOM objects are doing.